# Magento gets stuck when generating Google Sitemap

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps

When I try to generate my Google Sitemaps Magento loops and does not stop.
Here is sitemap url : http://www.soloshop.it/sitemap.xml

What could the problem be? Any ideas? Thanks

**UPDATE 20/11/2014**

I moved the entire site in localhost and google sitemap generation went fine!
On dedicated server I still have problems.
Everytime i generate the sitemap, it writes `11853 bytes` and then hangs.
Ideas on how to debug the problem?
Errors that I previously reported were not related to sitemap generation, so i removed them.

Comment: Have you enabled logging and checked system.log and exception.log?

Comment: please see my answer *http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/726/mysql-keeps-hanging-queries-stuck-on-sending-data/137003#137003* in our case a slow mysql query was the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third party plugin messed all Magento up,without launching any errors. Managed to fix by removing it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you please share what plug-in was causing the problems and what exactly was the problem, so I can check if we are having the same issue?

Comment: Can't remember anymore because i did not manage the site all alone. Was something related with an auto sync between Magento and a management program (maybe Magmi!)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an execution time or memory limit issue. Please check your values on the server and try updating these via php.ini or .htaccess.